# Monitoring SQL statements application-side by attaching to w3wp/WebDev.WebServer.exe (SQL Sever)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, profiling

I must be missing something...

**Oracle** has simple, useful and free tools for attaching to a process and monitoring its SQL statements but I can't anything similar for **SQL Server**. This is incredibly useful across a number of scenarios, particularly when dealing with third-party assemblies (1). **ANTS** 6 seems to support something like this (2), though it doesn't allow you to view the stack-trace that lead to the query as **dynaTrace** does. I don't think **dotTrace** tracks parameter values, either.

Surely there's a widely available option for profiling SQL application-side?

(1) -
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511154646/http://blog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/02/09/sharepoint-lookup-value-performance/)

(2) -
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/performance/under-the-orm-hood-revealing-the-sql/

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server comes with a tool called [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx). You can use it to connect to a SQL Server instance, and you'll be able to see all SQL statements issued on that server.

You can then filter by Application Name, Username, etc. to only see the statements of the particular application you want to monitor.

[Here](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/) is also a free express version.

Comment: Thanks, I know you can use the standard profiler and filter by application, but I'm interested in tools that monitor this from the calling process... and if they provide the full-stack trace, all the better.